# The scales never lie (oh yes they do!)

Tags: liars, weighing

There are $10$ coins, one of which is a fake, and weighs either more or less than the others - you don't know which.

There are two sets of scales - one tells the truth, the other lies (always says equal weighings are unequal but either way, unequal weighings are either equal or wrong.) - you don't know which is which. The lying scales decisions are made by an AI unit - see comments.

Both scales only allow an equal number of coins on either side (and at least one) to be tested.

> **How many weighings are needed to find the fake coin?**

Comment: Is it correct that the lying scale only lies 50% of the time given that the coins don't weigh the same? Is this random? I.e. is it possible that it tells the truth 50 times in a row (though unlikely)? Can it show that the lighter coin is heavier, or will it always be lighter or equal?

Comment: The lying scale has a AI unit to choose between options as to hinder the tester as much as possible. The lying scale never gives a truthful result.

Comment: Then what's the 50/50?

Comment: That was me assuming my own conjecture that the AI unit chooses the options with a 50:50 ratio.

Comment: Which two options? If it always lies, then it will always show unequal coins as equal? Or will A>B, result in A=B or A<B with 50/50 chance (randomly, or intelligently)? And is the ratio still 50/50 if there's AI involved? Over how many trials? Can the AI choose the same output 50 times in a row, then the other output 50 times?

Comment: It's the second one - I'm going to drop the 50/50 bit.

Comment: If I weigh two equal weight coins on the lying scale with one on both sides, and then I do it again, will the results from both weighings be the same i.e. will it always say that the coin on the right side, for example, is heavier than the one on the left side?

Comment: @PiIsNot3 I feel like this has been answered. It will choose between options to hinder the tester as much as possible.

Comment: @PiIsNot3; [AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) learns from it's mistakes, so if a test tricks it this time, next time the test won't be so lucky.

Comment: @hdsdv OK, so in the case I mentioned I believe it will always say one side is heavier than the other consistently, because that would provide no information about the truthfulness of the scale, thus hindering the tester the most?

Comment: @PiIsNot3 it depends on what will be most useful to the tester. I think it's pretty clear that the problem is saying that the false scale will always put the tester in the worst-case scenario. This isn't nitpicking. It's how we prove that algorithms are optimal. We assume that everything goes as badly as possible and then count how many steps are required to solve in that worst-case case.

Comment: @hdsdv Yes, I understand the spirit of the problem, I'm just making sure I fully understand the behavior of the scales because I've seen plenty of logic puzzles that don't fully specify its restrictions and requirements, thus allowing for unintended or troll answers

Comment: @PiIsNot3 Be that as it may, it seems like this puzzle specified its restrictions and requirements pretty clearly in comment 2. The false scale does whatever is worst for the tester. I'll stand by my earlier response that this has been answered.

Comment: So do we have to assume, that the false scale will give the same answer for the same weighing? Otherwise the false scale could be easily identified by doing the same weighing multiple times until one gives a different result than before.

Comment: please, either update the question ith AI unit logic or retract it.

Answer (score 8):

In 5 moves :

> Lets say coins are ABCDEFGHJK. Plus symbol means weighing.
>  First try AB+CD and EF+GH.
>  There are four possibilities (well 3, both equal, both unequal or one equal and second not):
>
>  **A)** if both are equal, it is simple J or K, since I used normal scales (total 3 moves)
>
>  **B)** if both are unequal, I used "AI" scales, so for the rest I will use normal one - and it is solvable in 3 more moves:
>  ABC+DEF - if unequal like ABC>DEF, I will weigh ABC+GHJ (since I know GHJ is surely normal) and will either found it is in ABC as heavier coin, or in DEF as lighter coin - in both cases I need only one more weigh, something like A+B - which is heavier is the one, or in equal case it would be C. Same for DEF, only it will be lighter one.
>  similar solution for  ABC
>  If I found that ABC=DEF I will weigh ABC+GHJ and I will either found that GHJ is lighter (*heavier) so I weigh G+H and it would be lighter one (or *heavier) or J. If equal - it would be K coin.
>
>  **C)** Either AB+CD is equal or EF+GH is equal (but not both, since it would be **A)** solution) so I weigh J+K:
>  If J+K is equal, I used normal scales so I identified normal scales - Now I know which 4 it is (for example ABCD).
>  If J+K is unequal, I used "AI" scales so I know which one are normal scales - Now I know which 4 it is anyway, since one weigh was equal (for example ABCD).
>  Now I use normal scales like: ABC + EFG (EFG can't be with fake coin). Again like in **B)** now I will know if it is lighter or heavier and one more weigh for A+B left, or it is D if it was equal.

Comment: Is this optimal? It needs $\ge 4$ weightings for sure, but I'm not sure if we can do $4$ or not.